# SQL- UPDATE And SELECT command together

Tags: php, sql

so I have three tables orders,shipping,customers. And I want to update in customers table the import value to '88'. But in the PHP code I only have shipping.tracking_id. So I need to inner join the another tables (in the orders table I have the customers.id and the shipping.orderid) The tables looks like this:

**Customers**

| id | import | etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0 | etc |
| 5678 | 0 | etc |

**Orders:**

| customerid | orderid | etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Order_1234 | etc |
| 5678 | Order_1234 | etc |

**Shipping**

| tracking_id | orderid | etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1234 | Order_1234 | etc |
| t5678 | Order_1234 | etc |

I tried this code:

```
UPDATE customers inner join orders on orders.orderid = customers.id inner join shipping on shipping.orderid = orders.orderid SET customers.import = '88' WHERE shipping.tracking_id = '". $row["tracking_id"] ."';
```

Or this:

```
UPDATE customer set import WHERE (SELECT orders.customerid FROM shipping inner join orders on orders.orderid = shipping.orderid WHERE tracking_id = '12345678')
```

But no luck. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution

```
UPDATE `Customers` `cus` 
   SET `cus`.`import` = 88
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM `Shipping` `s`
        INNER JOIN `Orders` `o` on `o`.orderid = `s`.`orderid`
    WHERE `s`.`tracking_id` = 't5678' AND `cus`.`id` = `o`.`customerid`
);
```

*Tested on Mysql*

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you should do the following:

- Join shipping with orders;
- Join orders with customers
- Add a condition on shipping.tracking_id

The query will look like this:

```
UPDATE customers
    SET import = '88'
FROM customers c
    JOIN orders o on c.id = o.customerid
    JOIN shipping s on o.orderid = s.orderid
WHERE s.tracking_id = 't1234';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below;

update customers set import = '88' where id = (select orders.customerid from orders where orders.orderid =(select shipping.orderid from shipping where shipping.tracking_id ='tracking_id'))